# Remove Icon part of AdvancedDataGrid Header in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I would like to remove the Icon part of the header in the AdvancedDataGrid. I am however unable to find how to do this.

In the header of every column in the AdvancedDataGrid, on the right side, it shows a pipe symbol and some spacing. After a bit of digging, I found that it was the Icon part of the header. However, I do not use icons in my headers, and I need to use the complete header space for text. This is why the icon part needs te be removed.

Does anyone have an idea how we can do this?

Thanks in advance

Ronald Kamp 
Flex/Java Developer at Ordina Belgium

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is controlled by setting the **sortExpertMode** property to true.  Read up on this bad boy here:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_03.html

Essentially this causes the pipe and sorting icon to only be visible for the column that the control is currently being sorted by (as opposed to all of them at all times) and neither are visible on any column at runtime––that is, until sorting is initiated by the user.

Alternatively, if your data visualization needs don't call for anything special (multiple sorts, hierarchical data, etc.) you can use the mx.controls.DataGrid control just as effectively and get the behavior I described previously by default.

Hope this helps :)